# Replace %20 with a space in filenames?

Tags: shell-script, sed, filenames

I have a list of files that are using *%20* to indicate a space in their names.

I'm currently trying to do the following to change them all from %20 to a space " ".

```
for x in *.txt
  do mv $x $(echo $x | sed -e 's/%20/ /')
done
```

That doesn't play nice. It spits out this:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

But I do the same thing on some of my images when I'm importing them and it works fine:

```
for x in *_MG*.CR2
  do mv $x $(echo $x | sed -e 's/_MG/_IMG/')
done
```

Forgetting that one is using **.TXT** and the other is **.CR2**, what am I totally overlooking here?

Keeping in mind I'm using a work laptop so I can't add Homebrew to install any additional software. And it's Mac OS X for the OS.

Comment: "That doesn't play nice" Excellent scientific diagnosis, sir!

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to use sed, this can be handled by parameter expansion

```
mv -- "$x" "${x//%20/ }"
```

FWIW, I'd be replacing those `%20`s with an underscore (or something); I *hate* file names that contain spaces. But I guess learning how to write bash scripts that can handle spaces and other special characters in file names is a Good Thing. :)

As Izkata mentions in the comments, it's *very* important to quote parameters! Double quotes in bash (& related shells) aren't mere string delimiters, they also signify that you don't want word-splitting to occur. So if `x` contains a filename with a space in it `$x` will be treated as two arguments, but `"$x"` will be treated as a single argument. If we use single quotes we inhibit parameter expansion so `'$x'` just results in a literal string containing `$x`, which is generally not what we want. :)

PS. Thanks to Monsieur Chazelas for supplying the missing `--` in my command line. `--` indicates the end of options in the argument list; without it it's possible for file names commencing with `-` to be interpreted as options.

Comment: This was my thought as well, but it might be worth putting more emphasis on the reason for the OP's problem, which is the space, not the use of an unnecessary pipeline.

Comment: +1 for the two important editorial observations: avoid spaces in file names (stuff breaks...) and learn to handle them properly (so when stuff breaks it's not your fault, at least).

Comment: Can you explain to me how the `"${x//%20/ }"` part works. This was magic and exactly what I needed.

Comment: @DanijelJ, the `"${x//%20/ }"` part utilizes extended form of parameter expansion which is available in contemporary `bash` and other shells. Simple parameter expansion looks like `${parameter}` and by adding various modificators after the `parameter` you can tell your shell to perform additional operations on parameter value. The `${parameter/pattern/string}` form replaces a part of `parameter` that matches the `pattern` with the `string`, if `pattern` begins with `/` all matching parts are replaced.

Comment: For anyone interested in possibilities of extended parameter substitution, I would suggest to read a relevant section at [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).

Comment: @PM 2Ring Can you please add the content of your comment in your answer?

Comment: @DanijelJ The key reason this works and the version in your question doesn't, that both PM2Ring and Mr.Deathless sidestepped, is that you have to quote the arguments so the new space doesn't split the second filename into multiple arguments, as described in Anthon's answer

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas for the `--` to stop file names commencing with `-` from being treated as options. I keep forgetting to do that...

Answer (score 10):

Use `rename` and replace the `%20` with a space in all type of files:

```bsh
$ rename -n 's/%20/ /g' *

File%20with%20in00.yA2 renamed as File with in00.yA2
File%20with%20in01.h9H renamed as File with in01.h9H
File%20with%20in02.CNR renamed as File with in02.CNR
File%20with%20in03.PuP renamed as File with in03.PuP
File%20with%20in04.js8 renamed as File with in04.js8
File%20with%20in05.KdZ renamed as File with in05.KdZ
```

In OS X you can use a specialized tool such as the Perl-based [rename utility](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/). you can install it using popular package manager [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) : `brew install rename`

Note: remove `-n` option to perform actual renaming.

Comment: It might be good to mention that this only works on systems where the Perl `rename` utility is installed, i.e. Ubuntu. It may or may not work for all systems. IIRC, Mac OS X does not ship with the Perl rename utility by default, meaning it must be installed with Homebrew or similar.

Comment: I do not have access to be able to install any software on this mac. We only have general user access. Also, what does the `/g` part mean?

Comment: @DanijelJ Owkey. no problem. And `g` on the end means replace all matches with space, not just the first match.

Comment: @DanijelJ `rename` is just a perl script, you can also install it manually. Get it from [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch09_10.htm) (Example 9.5), paste it into a text file called `rename` and run `chmod +x rename` in Terminal. Please note that this version does *not* support `-n`.

Answer (score 7):

Since the output of the `mv` probably will have spaces you need to put double quotes around the result in order not to try and execute commands in the `for` loop like:

```
mv abc%20def abc def
```

where `mv` has too many arguments. These are the ones giving you the `usage:` message.

What you should do is:

```
for x in *_MG*.CR2
do 
  mv -- "$x" "$(printf '%s\n' "$x" | sed 's/_MG/_IMG/')"
done
```

Comment: the example using _MG to _IMG works perfectly fine. Those particular files mentioned in that example have no spaces in them. It was the replacing of `%20` with `" "` that was the pain.